# Hide (abstract) classes from Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, intellisense

I have several abstract classes is class library which would like to hide from Intelisence, how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Use the attributes, before the class declaration:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

**edit:** if the class code is in your solution, it won't ever hide:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/c2d2bd5a-97a5-4886-846d-759173476631/

Comment: Added but still see class in Intelisence.

Comment: Restarted and rebuilded but abstract classes till appears in Intelligence.

Comment: This works great for libraries, where you might have structural public classes that'll never be used by themselves. I guess OP was trying in the same solution.