# How to hide public classes from being seen in C# Editor IntelliSense only?

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes, access-modifiers

**Shortly,**

The `Browsable()` and `EditorBrowsable()` works with members. not class itself.

So, I need to hide the accessibility of class that I can't make it internal. Just hide it from code.

An `internal` access modifier will make it only accessible in assembly the class created.

**Why i need that?**

> I need some people can't access these classes. 
>   only I need writing it manually without showing in IntelliSense.

**Updated**

I mean all kind of types [ classes, structs, enums ].

When user or developer write for example Employee class it will not showing in intellisense. but its accessible and can be instantiated normally.

Comment: It's not clear what you are wanting... it sounds like you want to have public classes that people can still use, but you want to prevent them from showing up in IntelliSense? Why?

Comment: why isn't important. but how is important.   its self convenient for me.

Comment: Why *is* important, because there is no reason to do so. I'm fairly certain it's not possible though.

Comment: You don't have 500 rep to give.

Comment: It depends, where the class is located. If it's the same solution, you can't hide it, by design, as it described in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2d2bd5a-97a5-4886-846d-759173476631/why-does-editorbrowsable-not-hide-methods-in-intellisense?forum=csharpide) For the class in separate assembly you can use solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274784/hide-abstract-classes-from-intellisense) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086419/4728685) `EditorBrowsable` is working, but not for the classes in the same solution

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski. would you mind to answer it to make it solved. and Yes MSDN link you provided works. it must be in assembly not solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends, where the class is located. If it's the same solution, you can't hide it, by design, as it described in this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2d2bd5a-97a5-4886-846d-759173476631/why-does-editorbrowsable-not-hide-methods-in-intellisense?forum=csharpide)

> It won't hide them from you because you are the developer (of the
>   solution) not the user (of the assembly).

For the class in a separate assembly you can apply the
`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute together with `[Browsable(false)]`